# Calculate mean by inclusive levels - expanding window based on entire groups

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data with some values ('value') and a grouping variable ('level'):

```
# Sample data frame
df <- data.frame(value = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
                 level = c("A2","A3","A1","A2","A1","A3","A2","A1","A3","A2"))

    value level
1      1     A2
2      0     A3
3      1     A1
4      0     A2
5      1     A1
6      1     A3
7      1     A2
8      1     A1
9      0     A3
10     0     A2
```

Conceptually, I assume that "A1" is the lowest level and "A3" the highest. I want to calculate mean value by including more and more groups in the calculation, like an 'expanding window', but based on *entire groups*, not on individual rows. Thus, for each group, the calculation will include values of the focal group *and* values in all other lower level groups.

I want the levels "A2" and "A3" to be inclusive. This means that when the focal level is "A2", the calculation includes values in group "A2" *and* values in the lower level "A1". When calculating the mean value of "A3", the calculation includes all values in the focal level "A3", *and all lower levels*, i.e. also values in group "A2" and "A1".

I aim to have an output like this:

```
  MeanValue  level
1      1.00     A1 # mean of level A1
2      0.71     A2 # mean of level A2 and A1
3      0.60     A3 # mean of level A3, A2, and A1
```

Could someone show me how to code this? I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 arrange(level) %>%
 mutate(mean_value = map_dbl(.x = seq_along(level), ~ mean(value[1:.x]))) %>%
 group_by(level) %>%
 summarise(mean_value = last(mean_value))

  level mean_value
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 A1         1    
2 A2         0.714
3 A3         0.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two `data.table` alternatives. As above, cumulative mean is calculated, but here `base` and `data.table` functions are used.

```
setDT(df)[order(level), .(level = unique(level),
                          mean_value = (cumsum(value) / .I)[!duplicated(level, fromLast = TRUE)])]

setDT(df)[order(level), .(level = unique(level),
                          mean_value = (cumsum(value) / .I)[rev(rowid(rev(level))) == 1])]

#    level mean_value
# 1:    A1  1.0000000
# 2:    A2  0.7142857
# 3:    A3  0.6000000
```

---

Although speed is not an issue for OP, it could be worth noting for future visitors that even on a modest data set, 200 groups with 200 rows each, these alternatives are both considerably faster than the `tidyverse` code.

Prepare data for benchmark, 200 groups with 200 rows each:

```
ng = 2e2
n = 2e2

set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(value = rbinom(ng * n, 1, 0.5),
                level = rep(seq(ng), each = n)

df3 = df
df4 = df
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark(
  f1 = {
    d1 = df %>%
      arrange(level) %>%
      mutate(mean_value = map_dbl(.x = seq_along(level), ~ mean(value[1:.x]))) %>%
      group_by(level) %>%
      summarise(mean_value = last(mean_value))
  },
  
  f2 = {
    d2 = df %>%
      arrange(level) %>%
      summarise(mean_value = cummean(value)[!duplicated(level, fromLast = TRUE)], 
                level = unique(level)) %>%
      select(level, mean_value)
  },
  
  f3 = {
    d3 = setDT(df3)[order(level), .(level = unique(level), mean_value = (cumsum(value) / .I)[!duplicated(level, fromLast = TRUE)])]
  },
  
  f4 = {
    d4 = setDT(df4)[order(level), data.table(level = level, mean_value = cumsum(value) / .I)[rev(rowid(rev(level))) == 1]]
  },
  times = 10L)
```

Result:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
#   f1 2834.601301 2869.658601 3052.233971 3030.448801 3191.671301 3303.532801    10
#   f2  127.474801  130.049101  138.202461  135.293550  141.301601  173.230901    10
#   f3    2.929702    3.401802    3.706061    3.450152    3.838801    5.585200    10
#   f4    3.888700    3.984301    4.372161    4.166951    4.844901    5.198001    10

all.equal(as.data.frame(d1), d2)
all.equal(as.data.frame(d1), as.data.frame(d3))
all.equal(as.data.frame(d1), as.data.frame(d4))
all.equal(as.data.frame(d1), as.data.frame(d4))
all.equal(as.data.frame(d1), as.data.frame(d5))
# TRUE
```

---

Another approach would be a non-equi join. A bit slower in this particular case, competing with the cumulative mean trick, but it is more general and can handle more complex functions.

```
setDT(df)[ , level := factor(level)]
df[.(level = sort(unique(df$level))), on = .(level <= level),
   .(mean_value = mean(value)), by = .EACHI]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to make use of `cummean`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(level) %>% 
   summarise(mean_value = cummean(value)[!duplicated(level, 
       fromLast = TRUE)], level = unique(level)) %>% 
   select(level, mean_value)
#  level mean_value
#1    A1  1.0000000
#2    A2  0.7142857
#3    A3  0.6000000
```